# If there's even one non-english character in any entry in a column I want have 'TRUE' in another column

Tags: postgresql

There are several entries in the column, eng characters with non english characters, eng characters numbers/symbols, non eng characters with numbers/symbols etc. If there's even one non-english character in any entry in the column, I want 'TRUE' in the adjacent column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies
WHERE name LIKE '%[a-z]%';
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: This code does not write anything to an adjacent column. You want to save true or false in a column on each row? Also, you originally tagged postgresql, then added a few tags, what is your database?

Comment: You are correct, that it doesn't edit anything in the adjacent column, currently I am trying to get the code run for getting the results, later I could get the true, once I have the filtered results. Secondly, database is postgresql!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). Here's a regular expression that will match all [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) printable characters along with tab (`\t`), new-line/line-feed (`\n`), and carriage return (`\r`).

```
SELECT
    *,
    name ~ '[^\t\n\r\x20-\x7E]' AS has_bad_chars
FROM companies
```

Now this will match any character that's not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, , `.`, `;`, `:`, `"`, `'`, `/`.

Comment: This is woking, but when it comes to entries like 'abc.com' it's returning, 'TRUE' for it as well. If the entry has symbols like .;:"'/ (anything of this sort) along with english characters I want 'FALSE' for that not TRUE.

Comment: Using code: SELECT *, name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;”:<.,.}?-]' AS has_bad_chars FROM "companies"; it gives me : 'TRUE' for 'abc;:' when I want false as the column name for true/false is has_bad_characters! and also if the entry is 'abc - abc' it says 'TRUE' for this as well.

Comment: Basically code is not handling two or more characters with english terms and " - " ("space hyphen space") correctly. For both these conditions it should say "FALSE" i.e. it doesn't have bad characters.

Comment: @Sahil Can you list the exact characters and symbols you want to support?

Comment: "So, Here I want a response for 'abc.com:;' and 'abc.com - Something' to be 'FALSE' instead of TRUE. My current code is: SELECT name,name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;:""<.,.}?-]' AS has_bad_chars
FROM companies;"

Comment: @Sahil See my update. It now accounts for all printable ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the assumption that the adjacent column you mention is defined in the table as 
has_non_english_char  boolean then try

```
update companies
   set has_non_english_char = name  ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9_.,/$]';
```

]
Alternatively look into [character classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) or include additional characters in the above. Note: The regular expression should include the 'English' characters you want to allow.

Comment: Thanks for replying to begin with. Code works well, however I also want to include '-' in the number of characters, however, whenever I type '-' anywhere along the characters, the code gives an error : invalid regular expression: invalid character range

Comment: you have any idea?

Comment: Try escaping as within the [ ] - has special meaning, Try '[^A-Za-z0-9_.,/$\-]'

Comment: This works, however, there are now other issues. Using code: SELECT *, name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;”:<.,.}?-]' AS has_bad_chars FROM companies; it gives me : 'TRUE' for 'abc;:' when I want false as the column name for true/false is has_bad_characters! and also if the entry is 'abc - abc' it says 'TRUE' for this as well.

Comment: Basically code is not handling two or more characters with english terms and " - " ("space hyphen space") correctly. For both these conditions it should say "FALSE" i.e. it doesn't have bad characters.

Comment: Look into the alternative mentioned in my the initial answer, particular [:punct:] and/or [:print:] (there are others that that may satisfy your need). As for the ' - ' issue in the current there is not a space in the regexp expression so add i also (in a regexp a space is just a space) and escape the dash and others  so
name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|\]\[{’;”:<.,.}?\- ]'
basically if you want to allow the character and it fails try escaping it.

Comment: Didn't really help much. "So, Here I want a response for 'abc.com:;' and 'abc.com - Something' to be 'FALSE' instead of TRUE. My current code is: SELECT name,name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;:""<.,.}?-]' AS has_bad_chars
FROM companies;" (Paraphrased, to make it easier to understand!)

Comment: I added a second answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the preferred SO protocol, but I think another answer may be better than just expanding a previous one. If not community please forgive me.
Run:

```
with companies as 
   ( select  * from (values ('abc.com:;'), ('abc.com - "Something')) as c(name)) 
SELECT 'My RE',name,name ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|\][{’\;:"<.,.}? -]'  has_bad_chars, 'f' desirded FROM companies
union 
SELECT 'Your RE',name,name ~  '[^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;:""<.,.}?-]', 'f'  from companies
order by 2,1 desc;
```

Let's examine the RE themselves and see the difference:

```
    My RE       [^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|\][{’\;:""<.,.}? -]
    Your RE     [^A-Za-z0-9&_`!@#$^&*()_+=\|][{’;:""<.,.}?-]
                                            ^^^

Notice the difference at the indicated position. You have '|]' while I have '|\]' also I later have a space.
```

See the regular expression reference from @cpburnz earlier, in particular section "9.7.3.2. Bracket Expressions".
Your RE breaks down to '[^...][...]' which breaks the RE into looking for 2 distinct set of characters telling the RE engine to find 'any character not in the first bracketed expression' followed immediately by 'any character that is in the second bracketed expression' 
The difference is I escaped the right bracket ] thus removing its special meaning in the RE and making it just another character. This is the nature of REs the exact individual characters can make all the difference. If you are going to do much of this type of stuff study REs intently. 
Good luck finding the exact RE you need, its out there you just need to work with it until you find it.